# What is non-inheritance hierarchy?

Tags: oop

Exercise from T.Budd book:
"In an object-oriented inheritance hierarchy each level is a more specialized form of the
preceding level. Given one more example of a hierarchy found in everyday life that
has this property. There are other types of hierarchy found in everyday life that are
not inheritance hierarchies. Give an example of a non-inheritance hierarchy."

What is an example of "non-inheritance hierarchy"??? 
Composition/aggregation are suitable?

Thanks

Comment: "Composition/aggregation are suitable?" - Yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood you are to give a real life example. There are a lot of things you can think of.
Eg. the hierarchy in a company.

```
CEO - Technical Team Leader - Developer
                            - Architect
    - CFO - acountant
    - secretary of the CEO
```

As far as skills go, the secretary of the CEO is not a more specialized CEO and neither is the developer.

Comment: Maybe i am missed something, but i can not see hierarchy between secretary and boss.

Comment: In a company schema the top is the CEO, all the rest are beneath him.